# Computer suddenly very slow

Tags: windows-10, performance, desktop-computer, intel-core-i5

I'm currently using a Dell computer, running on an Intel i5 CPU, which is about two years old. It's always had pretty good performance for the few video games I play – Minecraft and Sims, mostly – and in general.

However, recently, it's begun to lag horrendously. Minecraft has started performing terribly (even with 0 mods and the lowest playable graphics settings), Sims has ridiculously long load times and gradually becomes slower until eventually, I have to restart it or risk crashing the game (or sometimes my full PC) after only about an hour. Even Chrome will start to slow down or crash if I open more than five or six tabs. I've been experiencing lag in online games, despite having a pretty decent and completely stable Ethernet connection – I don't know enough to tell for sure, but I'm thinking that may be a result of the performance slowdown, too.

I've tried a ton of things. I check for viruses regularly and have done in-depth scans with multiple products since the problems started, and haven't found anything. I tried clearing out hard drive space, doing a deep clean of all my files, folders, and apps, fixing any file errors or shortcuts, everything a cleanup software is capable of. It did very little to help performance. I'm not an expert, but as far as I know, 30% of hard drive disk space open shouldn't be too little to function properly.

If anyone knows what may be causing the problem, I'd love to hear any solutions. Having to restart my PC five times over five hours and being unable to use it efficiently has been infuriating. My specs and any potentially helpful details are below:

- Windows 10 OS
- Computer:

  - Intel i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10 GHz
  - AMD Radeon R7 240 graphics chipset
  - 8 GB of DDR3 memory
- I currently use AVG Antivirus software
- The only full programs I have set to start up on boot are Spotify and Discord

What should I do to diagnose the problem and understand what is happening? 
What should I be looking for?

Comment: The drive is probably failing. Start by checking its health with the default Windows error correction tool.

Comment: I already did, it was one of the first things I checked. According to the diagnostic, my drive is fully healthy. Sorry, I forgot to mention that bit.

Comment: Next thing, reinstall/update the graphics drivers.

Comment: Did that too, everything is fully up to date.

Comment: What diagnostics did you run?  The behavior you describe is typically caused by a failing HDD.  It could also be your AV being to aggressive.  The fact this effects Chrome is an indication this isn’t a GPU driver issue.  It could be caused by Windows downloading a feature update in the background but you would have been given a notification of that fact.

Comment: I used glary utility software to check for fragmentation and file errors and all the disk cleanup stuff and used Windows commands to check disk health and status. According to the results, my disks are fine. Do you think turning off my AVG would help?

Comment: Most disk issues like this will not be detected until it starts to affect system files. The latency you seem to have could be explained by I/O errors.  Unless you ping is high, it's not network latency, but your system having trouble accessing files.

Comment: Do you know where I could find information on how to identify/repair errors like that? I'm not too familiar with them.

Comment: @Jay Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive’s SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.